# Using AppleScript to move files to Linux server

Tags: applescript

When moving files to my Linux box, I usually fire up the Terminal and do something like this:

```
1) Find the file in finder
2) Open a terminal window
3) cd <directory where file is>
4) scp <file> me@host:/home/me/
5) ssh into the remote server
6) cd /home/me
7) mv <file> /directory/where/it/needs/to/be
```

Not hard, but this minute or so of tedious work is a waste of my time.

I've only written the most minimal of AppleScript. As a way to get more familiar with it, I'd figure I'd write a script to automate this process. I imagine something like this:

```
1) I find the file with Finder
2) Right click on the file and select "Send to server" (or maybe I use a hotkey instead). It would have the IP address of my main server as a default but it might also give me the option of sending to another IP addresses.
3) The script prompts me to type in remote directory server where it should go
4) Do more productive things with my time
```

I know Perl and can handle the back end code that would actually upload and move the file on the server. I just need to be able to create the interface that I interact with and then launches my Perl script.

I'm hoping someone can save me a few hours of research and trial and error by pointing me in the right direction. I'm not really sure where to begin. I'll be sure to share my script here when done.

Comment: How about NFS-mounting your Linux box to your Mac and dragging files from your Mac straight to the NFS-mounted directory?

Comment: It's a production server. I don't want to introduce anything like that to it.

Comment: Plus, even if I went that route, I would still need to manually move the file on the remote server.

Comment: Choose Automator for that task. Reason: all actions you need are there - connecting servers, selecting and moving files plus use it as service in right click context. I'd just handle some extra stuff like dialogs with applescript (also possible from within automator). If you want to save time that's your way to go.

Comment: OK, thanks. So I create a new automator task and I'm asked to create workflow, application, service, print plugin, etc. What do I want. An application?

Answer (score 0):

Choose Automator for that task. Reason: all actions you need are there - connecting servers, selecting and moving files plus use it as service in right click context. I'd just handle some extra stuff like dialogs with applescript (also possible from within automator). If you want to save time that's your way to go.

If you create a new task, choose service that you can access it from contextual menus. More details see here: https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-automator-services--cms-20782